# How to send an client specific answer from an server using rabbitMq

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

This solution is very slow, I guess it is the creation of many queues for the answer I send to one client. Is there a way I could just create two queues, like a request and response queue, and then filter for a unique identifier so that the client can wait for its own answer? Or do I need for each client an own queue to receive an answer?

This class is used for the payLoad, I use serialization to convert it to a message.

```
 namespace PayLoad
    {
        public class PayLoad
        {
            public string clientQueue { get; set; } // the queue where the client listens to to receive a response
            public int x { get; set; }
            public int y { get; set; }
            public int response { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

This is my helper class for the communication, needs some refactoring, but this is only a proof of concept.

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace PayLoad
    {
        public class Job
        {
            static string _serverQueue = "ElvisDTS_Incomming";
    
            public void doWork(string payLoadMessage)
            {
                var ThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                Console.WriteLine($"[x] Received {payLoadMessage} on thread {ThreadId}");
                var payLoad = DeserializeData<PayLoad>(payLoadMessage);
                payLoad.response = payLoad.x + payLoad.y;
                var responseMessage = SerializeData(payLoad);
                Console.WriteLine($"[x] Sending response to {payLoad.clientQueue} on thread {ThreadId}");
                RabbitSend(payLoad.clientQueue, responseMessage);           
            }
    
            public static void askServer(int x, int y)
            {
                var payload = new PayLoad();
                payload.x = x;
                payload.y = y;
                payload.clientQueue = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                payload.response = -1;
                var clientMessage = SerializeData(payload);
                RabbitSend(_serverQueue, clientMessage);
    
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
                var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                var channel = connection.CreateModel();
    
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: payload.clientQueue,
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);
    
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    var result = DeserializeData<PayLoad>(message);
    
                    Console.WriteLine("The result is " + result.response);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: payload.clientQueue,
                                     autoAck: true,
                                     consumer: consumer);
            }
    
            private static void RabbitSend(string queueName, string message)
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
                using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                                         durable: false,
                                         exclusive: false,
                                         autoDelete: false,
                                         arguments: null);
    
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    
                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                         routingKey: queueName,
                                         basicProperties: null,
                                         body: body);
                }
            }
    
            public static void runServer(string queueName)
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
                var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                var channel = connection.CreateModel();
    
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);
    
                channel.QueuePurge(queueName);
    
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    var job = new Job();
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => job.doWork(message));
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                                     autoAck: true,
                                     consumer: consumer);
            }
    
            private static string SerializeData<T>(T requestStruct)
            {
                var settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings();
                settings.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = Int32.MaxValue;
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, requestStruct);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
    
            private static T DeserializeData<T>(string xml)
            {
                var settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings();
                settings.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = Int32.MaxValue;
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
                var ms = GenerateStreamFromString(xml);
                return ((T)(serializer.ReadObject(ms)));
            }
    
            private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
            {
                return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
            }
        }
    }
```

My client looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace RabbitSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) PayLoad.Job.askServer(42, i);
            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And my server like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RabbitServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PayLoad.Job.runServer("ElvisDTS_Incomming"));

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find the full running sample project on gitHub. https://github.com/NickDinges/RabbitSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question

> This solution is very slow, I guess it is the creation of many queues.

### Answer

Not exactly. The way you create queues may cause [channel leaks](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#channel-leaks) (which will, in turn, cause memory pressure and thus slowing down RabbitMQ broker), but that is not the main issue ([document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html)).

> For applications that use multiple threads/processes for processing, it is very common to open a new channel per thread/process and not share channels between them.

On the other hand, you should always think of **long-lived connections** ([document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connections.html)) to prevent exhaustion of resources (file handles and TCP sockets).

> All protocols supported by RabbitMQ are TCP-based and assume long-lived connections (a new connection is not opened per protocol operation) for efficiency.

---

### Question

> Is there a way I could just create two queues, like a request and response queue, and then filter for a unique identifier so that the client can wait for its own answer?

### Answer

No, that is not how RabbitMQ works.

You *can* create two queues. In that case, your clients will act as [consumers](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html) to consume response queue. Each of your clients will receive the message (answer) at almost equal opportunity (default with round-robin dispatch). There is no guarantee that client A will receive message A. Even if client A `nack` message B and requeue it, next time client C may pick it up.

---

### Question

> Or do I need for each client an own queue to receive an answer?

### Answer

It totally depends on your requirements. If you need several queues to handle *different* tasks, then yes.

To prevent [channel leaks](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#channel-leaks) and/or [high channel churn](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#high-channel-churn), you can

- Declare all response queues for once only (if you know those queues in advance)

  - That will also save some time without declaring the same queue all over again (though that operation is idempotence)
- Get channel from a channel pool ([document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#high-channel-churn)).

> While with some workloads this is a natural state of the system, long lived channels should be used instead when possible.

Comment: To be more concrete I try to decouple a web application from business logic running in a windows service. The requests are slow so I try to wait in an Async way.So each client is a session waiting for a specific answer, so opening two channels could be static declared, but how can I filter to only receive the callback when the message is the answer for the specific session?
Thanks ;-)

Comment: @NickD - The routing happens at the `exchange` and `queue` (with binding key) level. Say you only have one *response* queue. All callbacks with different session ID will be pushed to that queue. You client is the `consumer` listening to that queue. But the routing cannot be done on `consumer` level. That is why you cannot filter any message that has already been pushed in the queue.